# Problem while trying to execute ant file in java

Tags: eclipse, variables, build, compiler-errors, ant

I'm trying to compile a service using a java ant file as appears below:

[image]

and my buid-jar.xml looks like this:

[image]

the problem i have is that eclipse is not recognizing the enviroment variables and it takes the names literally causing an error on building time:

[image]

Both, paths and ant files does exists in these routes in my user folder, but i don't know why this  error is happening. I'm using jdk 1.8.0_45.

Any idea? Sorry i had to attach screenshots instead code, but the proxy of the company network that i work for doesn't allow me to navigate on stackoverflow.

Comment: What's it doing on line 38?

Comment: @nitind <classpath refid="classpath" /> ? it supposed is the place where java must load the 3rd party libraries. In my case: swagger and javax ejb, persist and rest libraries.